# How to avoid the "no rows" message while loading data in ag-grid

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ag-grid, ngrx-store

I have an ag-grid which pulls data from the backend via restful call and routed through NGRX pattern.

```
   <ag-grid-angular #agGrid class="ag-theme-fresh" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                 [rowData]="rowData"
                 [pagination]="true" [paginationAutoPageSize]='true' [enableSorting]="true"
                 [rowSelection]="rowSelection" [enableColResize]="true"
                 [enableFilter]="true" [rowClassRules]="rowClassRules" (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)"
                 (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
                 (gridReady)="onReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

I have 2 scenarios where the grid loads the data.

*scenario 1:* The first time I load it on page load (via ngrx store )

```
  this.QueueItems$ = this.store.select(fromStore.getQueueItems);
```

*scenario 2*:  The 2nd time I have a button which refreshes the data in the grid from another store.

```
     <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Refresh Grid" 
     (click)="handleOnGridRefesh($event)" matTooltipPosition="left"
      style="right: 2%;top: 0;margin-top: 7px;position: absolute;z-index:4">
     <i class="fa fa-refresh" style="color:#455A64" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>


   //note:getQueueItemsStore is a different store ( ngrx) from getQueueItems
   handleOnGridRefesh($event: any) {
this.QueueItems$ = this.store.select(fromStore.getQueueItemsStore);
 }
```

My issue is after I click on the button to refresh the grid, there is a brief time delay of 500ms to 1 sec where the ag grid is pulling the data and displays the "No rows to show" overlay.

**How can I transition smoothly without [the overlay in between as shown here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AU7w.jpg)**

Comment: How does the queue items get transformed into ag grids input (rowData)?
Change detection strategy preventing redraw?
You can remove that message: `suppressNoRowsOverlay: true,`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I used `suppressNoRowsOverlay: true` as bc1105 suggested in their comment, but this always hides the overlay. I wanted to still show the overlay if there was no data after it was done loading. To overcome this, I did the following:

```js
this.gridOptions.suppressNoRowsOverlay = true;
this.service.getData()
  .subscribe(data => {
    if (!data || !data.length) {
      this.gridOptions.suppressNoRowsOverlay = false;
      this.gridOptions.api.showNoRowsOverlay();
    }
```

Comment: This won't affect the loading overlay. There are separate properties for that—`gridOptions.suppressLoadingOverlay` and `gridOptions.api.showLoadingOverlay()`

Comment: Has anyone experienced the issue where the LoadingOverlay does not appear while doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Ag-grid provides two basic methods:

1. `this.gridApi.showNoRowsOverlay();` (Show "No Rows To Show" message).
2. `this.gridApi.hideOverlay();` (Clear All overlays).

If you have a specific requirement then refer to https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/angular/overlays/